# IndexOutOfBoundsException for arraylist

Tags: java, algorithm, merge

Can someone explain to me why this piece of code is throwing an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

```
public static Hull merging(Hull HullA, Hull HullB) {
    Hull finalHull = new Hull();
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    if (HullA.list.get(i) >= HullB.list.get(j))
    {
        finalHull.list.add(HullA.list.get(i));
        i++;
    }
    else 
    {
        finalHull.list.add(HullB.list.get(j));
        j++;
    }

    return finalHull;
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: as a sidenote, this variable naming makes even that small method horrendous to read.

Comment: Have you tryied to use a Debugger to find it out?

Comment: @Jens yes, i did and it says this line if (HullA.list.get(i) >= HullB.list.get(j))
but I am not sure how to fix this problem even after googling and setting a value to the list if the list is empty, does not seem to work

Comment: @KevinEsche what would be a good way to name the variables then? pls suggest.

Comment: @Amy then its simple, your list is empty and by the way for what reason you are incrementing  i and j??

Comment: check if the list is empty. You get the exception, because you can not get the element at index 0 if the list is empty

Comment: @Amy start variables with lowercase `Hull hullA` to make a difference to classnames. give them more logical names than `i` and `j`.

Comment: @Amy from your code its not possible to identify which is Class and which is object. In java there are some conventions to name variable, variable name should start from lowercase letter, this is a basic rule

Answer (score 0):

This method will always add first element(index=0) of HullA or HullB to finalHull list. That increment lines `i++` and `j++` are pointless.

Additionally that code can throw `IndexOutOfBound Exception` if and only if `HullA` or `HullB` has size 0.

P.S. Start your variable names with lower-case letter.

P.S. Dont use counters (i++ , j++) if the code will be processed just one time and then counter will be initialized again.

P.S. Dont use lists in an object statically. Use like that : `finalHull.getList().add()`

Answer (score -2):

You are directly comparing the values of the lists and increment the counters.
before comparing there should be check for the size of both lists.

Size of HullA, HullB could be smaller than the index you are trying to retrieve.

HullA.list.get(i)
if HullA.size =4
and you are trying to retrieve 
HullA.get(5) then it would throw Araayindexoutofbound error.

Comment: i and j can only have value 0.